# Can Anyone Explain the work flow of IExceptionHandler with Sample Client Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am facing below issues in this Sample:

I am not able to find `IsOutermostCatchBlock` in `ExceptionContext`

If Exception occurs, this `HandleAsync` method is executing twice.

(http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling)

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public virtual Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!ShouldHandle(context))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

            return HandleAsyncCore(context, cancellationToken);
        }

        public virtual Task HandleAsyncCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context,
                                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HandleCore(context);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public virtual void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
        }

        public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {    
             return context.ExceptionContext.IsOutermostCatchBlock;
        }

    }

    public class OopsExceptionHandler : CustomExceptionHandler
    {
        public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
            {
                Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                          "Please contact support@contoso.com so we can try to fix it."
            };
        }

        private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
        {
            public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response =
                                 new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
                response.RequestMessage = Request;
                return Task.FromResult(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you problem is.  HandleAsync does get called multiple times.  That's why there is the ShouldHandle guard. I don't know what you mean by you can't find "IsOutermostCatchBlock".  Does code you have shown compile?

Comment: If i am using context.ExceptionContext.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel means this code is compling.

Answer (score 22):

### CatchBlock.IsTopLevel

`IsOutermostCatchBlock` does not exists.
Use **`CatchBlock.IsTopLevel`** instead:

```
public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
{
  return context.ExceptionContext.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel;
}
```

Source on NuDoq: [ExceptionHandlerContext](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandlerContext) and [ExceptionContextCatchBlock](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/System.Web.Http/ExceptionContextCatchBlock)