# WebApi v2 ExceptionHandler not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How comes that a custom `ExceptionHandler` is never called and instead a standard response (not the one I want) is returned?

Registered like this

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
```

and implemented like this

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ExceptionResponse
        {
            statusCode = context.Exception is SecurityException ? HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized : HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            message = "An internal exception occurred. We'll take care of it.",
            request = context.Request
        };
    }
}

public class ExceptionResponse : IHttpActionResult
{
    public HttpStatusCode statusCode { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public HttpRequestMessage request { get; set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode);
        response.RequestMessage = request;
        response.Content = new StringContent(message);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

and thrown like this (test)

```
throw new NullReferenceException("testerror");
```

in a controller or in a repository.

**UPDATE**

I do not have another `ExceptionFilter`.

I found a trigger for this behavior:

Given URL

```
GET http://localhost:XXXXX/template/lock/someId
```

sending this header, my `ExceptionHandler` works

```
Host: localhost:XXXXX
```

sending this header, it doesn't work and the built-in handler returns the error instead

```
Host: localhost:XXXXX
Origin: http://localhost:YYYY
```

This might be an issue with CORS requests (I use the WebAPI CORS package globally with wildcards) or eventually my ELMAH logger. It also happens when hosted on Azure (Websites), though the built-in error handler is different.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you happen to have an exception filter too? Also can you share how your controller or repository code looks like...we want to make sure that you are not catching it somewhere and converting it to HttpResponseException or something in which case exception handler would not get invoked.

Comment: @KiranChalla: Interesting update above, thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turns out the default only handles outermost exceptions, not exceptions in repository classes. So below has to be overridden as well:

```
public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
{
    return context.ExceptionContext.IsOutermostCatchBlock;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

WebAPI v2 does not use `IsOutermostCatchBlock` anymore. Anyway nothing changes in my implementation, since the new code in `ShouldHandle` still prevents my Error Handler. So I'm using this and my Error Handler gets called once. I catch errors in Controllers and Repositories this way.

```
public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
{
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since this question got so much attention, please be aware that the current solution is the one [linked](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/DefaultExceptionHandler.cs) by @JustAMartin in the comments below.

Comment: Notice also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038800/can-anyone-explain-the-work-flow-of-iexceptionhandler-with-sample-client-applica It seems they have replaced IsOutermostCatchBlock with IsTopLevel

Comment: Thanks for the update @Martin. Still it's the same, don't know why Controller errors don't get handled with the standard implementation.

Comment: I just found a solution for exception handling with CORS, see if this might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189315/exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-custom-exception-handler-never-reach-top-level-whe/24634485#24634485  It seems even ASP.NET team is not using ShouldHandle anymore but they don't mention it anywhere, thus causing the confusion. I suggest you to forget the ExceptionHandler base class and implement your solution as ASP.NET team does: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/DefaultExceptionHandler.cs

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me, the only difference is I used public override instead of public virtual.

Comment: public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context) => true; does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The real culprit here is CorsMessageHandler inserted by EnableCors method in message processing pipline. The catch block intercept any exception and convert into a response before it can reach the HTTPServer try-catch block and ExceptionHandler logic can be invoked

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    CorsRequestContext corsRequestContext = request.GetCorsRequestContext();
    HttpResponseMessage result;
    if (corsRequestContext != null)
    {
    try
    {
        if (corsRequestContext.IsPreflight)
        {
        result = await this.HandleCorsPreflightRequestAsync(request, corsRequestContext, cancellationToken);
        return result;
        }
        result = await this.HandleCorsRequestAsync(request, corsRequestContext, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        result = CorsMessageHandler.HandleException(request, exception);
        return result;
    }
    }
    result = await this.<>n__FabricatedMethod3(request, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Workarounds can be found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189315/exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-custom-exception-handler-never-reach-top-level-whe/24634485#24634485