# Exceptions in ASP.NET Web API custom exception handler never reach top level when CORS is enabled

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception, cors

I have created a custom Web API global exception handler like this:

```cs
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        // here I handle them all, no matter sync or not
    }

    public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // not needed, but I left it to debug and find out why it never reaches Handle() method
        return base.HandleAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        // not needed, but I left it to debug and find out why it never reaches Handle() method
        return context.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel;
    }
}
```

I'm registering it in my Global.asax Application_Start:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
    new MyGlobalExceptionHandler());
```

Everything worked fine, no matter where I threw exceptions - inside controller methods or in my custom attributes above controller methods, and no matter if I call it from AJAX requests or directly from browser.

But then one day I needed CORS support for my AJAX requests. I enabled CORS globally as described in the article [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

```cs
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); // * is just for debugging purpose
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

At first everything seemed OK, CORS worked as expected, the server responded to OPTIONS request.

But the problems started when I wanted to check my authentication. Suddenly the exception was swallowed and I got an empty JSON `{}` response instead of my custom JSON formatted exception which I create in the Handle() method of my MyGlobalExceptionHandler.

While debugging, I was surprised to find that now for AJAX requests ShouldHandle() method is called only with IsTopLevel = false, thus the exception never bubbles up and never reaches my Handle() method. As soon as I disable CORS, everything works fine again (except cross-domain requests, of course).

**Why IsTopLevel is never true when I enable CORS? How should I fix this?**

*One more side effect is as follows. If CORS is disabled, then if I throw any exception inside Handle() method, it reaches the Application_Error handler in  Global.asax. But if I enable CORS and throw exceptions in my handler methods, these exceptions never reach Application_Error.*

### UPDATED WITH MORE DETAILS:

It seems, I found exactly when this is happening.

If I throw an exception in a controller method when CORS is enabled, then CORS doesn't kick in at all and does not send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. When the browser doesn't receive the header, it immediately disrupts the request and this disruption seems to affect also the exception handler - it never reaches ShouldHandle() method with IsTopLevel = true.
Chrome and Mozilla act like this even when I run AJAX request from a local html file to my websiet on IIS Express localhost.

But the situation is different on IE 11. When I open the html file there, it first asks me permissions to enable scripts. After I agree, then IE 11 ignores the fact that there are no CORS headers present and it doesn't disrupt the request, thus my exception handler receives  IsTopLevel = true and is able to return a customised error response.

I guess, this should be fixed in the Web API core - even if I throw exceptions, CORS should still be able to kick in and send its headers, so the browser accepts the response. I have created a minimal test case application and I'll send it to the ASP.NET Team on CodePlex.
[Link to the test project](http://1drv.ms/1sb6rRt).  (the project zip file will be marked, just click Download and ignore all the other files in that folder)

Comment: This could potentially be a bug...could you file an issue here with a standalone repro? http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Ok, I'll try to create a minimal test case project and maybe I'll look into the Web API source code to see what's going on there.

Comment: It seems like a related issue #2219 was reported on codePlex. https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2219

Answer (score 72):

I have found the source of confusion.

It seems, WebAPI by default is using this exception handler:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ExceptionHandling/DefaultExceptionHandler.cs

and it has major differences from the suggested exception handling in this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling

see chapter "Appendix: Base Class Details", where the code of default exception base class is given.

In the example it checks for `IsOutermostCatchBlock` (which now seems to be moved to `exceptionContext.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel`) to see if it's time to handle the exception. When CORS is enabled, such approach won't work for the reasons I described above. ASP.NET team said, this behavior is by design and they won't change anything.

I hope someone experienced will write an up-to-date article with instructions for doing exception handling the right way with and without CORS.

Currently I see two ways to work around this in my code:

- don't inherit my custom exception handler from `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler` but implement `IExceptionHandler` directly
- if inheriting from `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler`, override
  ShouldHandle method and return `true` always because `CatchBlock.IsTopLevel` might never have `true` value.

I tried both apporaches and they seem to work fine.

Comment: I thought I was going insane when my exception handler stopped working...

Comment: @JustAMartin I'd like to propose a 3rd option. In my case, I am using the exception handler on more than one project with one project without CORS turned on.

`public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            if (context.RequestContext.Configuration.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_CorsEnabledKey"))
            {
                return (bool)context.RequestContext.Configuration.Properties["MS_CorsEnabledKey"];
            }

            return base.ShouldHandle(context);
        }`

Comment: csteele- I like your suggestion and I am using it in my code.  I did run across a very strange problem.  It appears strings for ContainsKey and Properties in your post are not actually the same (comparing in Notepadd++).   I cannot tell what is different about them but this caused me to scratch my head until I used "MS_CorsEnabledKey" copied directly from the Properties keys.  It was not finding the key until I did that.  To see what I am talking about, copy both strings in your comment above into Notepad++.  Double click on the string and you will see that the other string does not highlight.

Comment: csteele- It looks like there is a strange hidden character between the o and r in the second MS_CorsEnabledKey.  You can double click on that string in your comment and see that only half the string is highlighted.  Hope this saves somebody else some time/head scratching.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! What a moronic issue. I independently finally narrowed down the issue to CORS, but had no idea how to resolve. All it took was to override `ShouldHandle` to always return true.

Comment: Good catch @eesh! I've tried to resolve the issue with the code I originally pasted, but it appears to something wrong with Stack Overflow's website. For anyone else who has the same issue, using Notepad++, toggle the Encoding from the menu to Ansi and then you will be able to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JustAMartin. Is there any way you could edit your post with a small example of each of your two workarounds? I'm trying to properly implement your first suggestion AKA implement IExceptionHandler directly. When I do this, it doesn't like my 'Handle' verbage