# Exceptions not caught in my OwinMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have created a OwinMiddleware to catch all unhandled exceptions on my api requests.

```
 public class UnhandledExceptionMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public UnhandledExceptionMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I throw some error in my controller function the catch block is not used and in this middleware seems that everything is fine. Why my catch block is not used?

### UPDATE

Here my Owin Config. The Invoke Method works only the catch is not working

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        
        // Enables use of spatial data types
        SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(HostingEnviron‌​ment.MapPath("~/bin"));

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        IContainer container = AutoFacConfig.Register(config, app);

        app.UseApplicationInsights();
        app.UseNLog();
        app.Use<UnhandledExceptionMiddleware>();
```

Comment: could be the order it falls in the pipeline.also something that has tripped me up in the past. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

Comment: Can you show how your are setting up your Owin pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this post. [Disable *all* exception handling in ASP.NET Web API 2 (to make room for my own)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201527/disable-all-exception-handling-in-asp-net-web-api-2-to-make-room-for-my-own)

You have to ovverride the default IExceptionFilter to catch exceptions in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware are invoked in the order in which they are added to the pipeline. Make sure that in this case the `UnhandledExceptionMiddleware` is added before any others during startup

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

        app.Use<UnhandledExceptionMiddleware>();

        //...Add other middleware

        //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```