# Web API 2 - Global Exception Handler not working with TaskCancellation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Code to demonstrate the problem:

- Assume Test Thing is an real implementation, such as DB invocation.
- The [documentation for Web API states](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) that unhanded exceptions will be caught in a global handler allowing you to process them.
- If I replace MyErrorHandler with an ExceptionFilter this does indeed work, except the code base I'm working with uses handlers because the error logic is a cross cutting concern and will be the same regardless of where the error came from.
- If the type of exception thrown is not a TaskCancelledException this invokes the handler as expected.
- I've tried the latest version of Web API too (5.2.3).
- The only work around is to add a try/catch block around everywhere that can throw this type of exception, needless to say this is painful and something I wish to avoid hence the use of the handler.

I hate to call this a bug given this is not my code, but after hours of attempts it's starting to feel that way.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            return await new TestThing().ExecuteAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }

    public class MyErrorHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }


    public class TestThing
    {
        public async Task<string> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Remove this to see the problem, I don't want to add these
            // try/catch statements all over the codebase.
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failure...");
            }

            return await Task.FromResult("Testing...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [WebApi v2 ExceptionHandler not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169889/webapi-v2-exceptionhandler-not-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of suggestions or answers I went with a custom message handler.

```
    public class AsyncFixHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // TODO: Log the issue here
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
```

This isn't ideal, but the try/catch is in one place. I'm using this successfully as the solution until something better comes along.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. For others who, like me, want their global exception handler and logger to be engaged, simply throw a new replacement exception instead of returning an HttpResponseMessage

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's and old bug, and there are some people reporting issues still. I suggest you to create an issue in ASP.NET [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) repo and use your workaround or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request/22621596#22621596) for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug report, I never found that in my many attempts to solve/research this. I can confirm this is still a problem in 5.2.3 though :(